# Is it OK to power a laptop using a voltage regulator?

Tags: adapter, laptop, dc-to-dc

I am trying to build a power module to power my laptop using a 12V lead acid car battery.
The output specs on the laptop charger read 19.0.V and 3.6 amperes.

I have tuned a voltage regulator with following specs to provide 19V output, but it didn't turn on the laptop.

When I increase the output to 19.5v it just turns on the laptop when there is no battery installed.

I have not tried to go on to higher voltages to avoid possible damage.

Are there any comments on this?

Voltage regulator specs:

```
Module Type: Non-isolated booster module (BOOST)
Input Voltage: DC 10V-40V
Input Current: 6A (MAX)
Static Working Current: 10mA (The higher output voltage, the higher static current)
Output Voltage: 10-50V Continuing Adjust
Output Current: 6A MAX, Please enhance heat sink if exceed 4A (The larger voltage difference between input and output, the smaller output current)
Constant Current Range: 0.2-6A
Output Power: 250W (max), suggest to leave some slack for long time work
Working Temperature: -40 to +85 degree Celsius (Please enhance heat sink for over-temperature)
Operating Frequency: 150KHz
Conversion Efficiency: 92%-96% (Efficiency is related to input, output voltage, current and voltage difference)
Input Reverse Connection Protection: YES
Mounting Type: 4PCS 3mm screw hole
Connection Mode: Lead wire output
Module Size: 70x36x13mm(LxWxH)
```

Comment: What are the voltage and current specs on the laptop?

Comment: As I've seen on the official adapter it says 19.0V and 3.6A

Comment: Would you please include a picture of your "voltage regulator" -- or is it really a "Boost Converter" with an adjustable voltage output? It's very important for answering this question. Your question says voltage regulator, but the text that describes it says boost converter... Which is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be OK to power up a laptop using a 12V to 19V boost converter. If you buy a car adapter from laptop manufacturer, it basically is just a boost converter.

But there are two things missing if you try to do it yourself.

The most important thing is that typically laptops communicate with the power supply in some ways so that the power supply must tell the laptop how much current is available and the laptop must be able to know how much current is available so that it can choose  a suitable charging current or it can also determine that there is not enough power available for any purpose and it will refuse to work.

Another thing is that the specs for how ripply, dirty, or noisy output from the supply is acceptable, so you still don't know how well the booster you got will work with the laptop.

Comment: The whole "communication" part is generally limited to the plug of the power supply, if any. The communicating part is a small chip inside the plug. From the plug to the power brick there are always only 2 wires.